# how to replace pyspark dataframe columns value with a dict

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe as show below

```html
  +++++++++++++++++++++
  colA | colB | colC |
  +++++++++++++++++++++
  123  | 3 | 0|
  222  | 0 | 1|
  200  | 0 | 2|
```

I want to replace the values in colB with a dict d to get the result like this.

d = {3:'a', 0:'b}

```html
  +++++++++++++++++++++
  colA | colB | colC |
  +++++++++++++++++++++
  123  | a | 0|
  222  | b | 1|
  200  | b | 2|
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use dataframe method [replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace) that actually does not clearly explains this use case.

To use a dictionary, you have to simply setting the specified dict as first argument, a random value as second argument, and the name of the column as third argument.

At least in Spark 2.2, a warning will be raised expliciting that, since the first argument is a dictionary, the second argument will be not take into account.

```
data = [
    (123,3,0),
    (222,0,2),
    (200,0,2)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,['colA','colB','colC'])

d = {3:'a', 0:'b}
df_renamed = df.replace(d,1,'colB')
df_renamed.show()

#  +++++++++++++++++++++
#  colA | colB | colC |
#  +++++++++++++++++++++
#  123  | a | 0|
#  222  | b | 1|
#  200  | b | 2|
```

Please also note that, *"When replacing, the new value will be cast to the type of the existing column"* , as reported inside the docs. By consequence, your column will be casted to string.